# How to get PATCH parameters of REST API in Yii 1.1?

Tags: api, rest, yii

Yii 1.1.16 brought `getPatch($paramName, $defaultValue=null)` and `getIsPatchRequest()` to life, but is there a way to loop through all PATCH parameters, without knowing their names? If a user wants to modify his tag line, but nothing else, how am I supposed to know that he wants to change `user_tag_line`?

Calling `getPatch()` gives
`Missing argument 1 for CHttpRequest::getPatch()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using

```
CJSON::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Is this safe, should this be used? Are there other ways of going about this?

Comment: if you did that on a put request, it would empty that stream, but don't know about patch request